# Transition not firing on hover

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to implement a sliding sidebar that activates when user hovers over `.sb-toggle` item. Hovering over it will cause the sidebar which is located just outside the view to slide in 10ems while also making the `.content` div shift to the right. But I can't get it to work properly. Transition fires for the `.sb-toggle` and `.content` items but sidebar isn't showing up.

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #404040;
  width: 10em;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -10em;
  top: 3em;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sb-toggle {
  background-color: #404040;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: 10em;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sb-toggle:hover {
  margin-left: 10em;
}

.sb-toggle:hover ~ .sidebar {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.sb-toggle:hover ~ .content {
  margin-left: 20em;
}
```

Edit: Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="sb-toggle"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: can you post your html, so we can see the structure?

Comment: Welcome.  Please create an [mcve].

Comment: I advise you to learn more about CSS selectors to see how they work. Regardless of what selector you use, it will ONLY go DOWN the DOM tree, never up. That's CSS's basic characteristic

Comment: Yup, you're right. First time using the sibling selector and it escaped my attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `.sb-toggle` div within `.sidebar`, and change `:hover` from `.sb-toggle` to `.sidebar`.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #404040;
  width: 10em;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -10em;
  top: 3em;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sb-toggle {
  background-color: #404040;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: 10em;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sb-toggle:hover {
  margin-left: 10em;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.sidebar:hover ~ .content {
  margin-left: 20em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="sb-toggle"></div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="content"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This was...pretty straightforward and it worked. Don't know why I hadn't thought about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify the starting point as well as the ending point.

For example:

```css
.sb-toggle {
  /* other stuff */
  margin-left: 0; /* <-- You need to add this */
  -moz-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: .sb-toggle item has no problem transitioning, so adding the starting point made no difference. However solution below solved my problem, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

The sibling selector `~` is only looking forwards in the DOM and not backwards.
hence the line `.sb-toggle ~ .sidebar` will never be executed.

From the MDN docs:

"The ~ combinator selects siblings. This means that the second element follows the first (though not necessarily immediately), and both share the same parent."

Made a tiny demo to show the mentioned behaviour:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jREMmb

You'd either have to swap order of DOM nodes or find another route to trigger the transition